# How can we keep Ren Faire fresh?

Tags: house-rules

After you've played Ren Faire with the same group for a while, the performance requirements seem old.  All of us have had to bellydance, act like a hyper kid, etc, etc.  I suppose we could crank out some more ideas for performances, but I'm wondering how others have kept it fresh.

How do you keep the performances from being "same old thing?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for peer pressure.  Perhaps the other players should have to vote on whether any particular performance is sufficient, with an understanding that doing the same old thing won't suffice.  Sing a new song, make up some new bellydance move, improvise a new reason for a tantrum... if players aren't doing it on their own, apply social pressure.  It doesn't have to be *good*, just new.

(I've never played Ren Faire, but I've seen games of Once Upon a Time get stale until the group applied social pressure to make people actually do something with the cards they play instead of just saying "and there was a prince there, and a horse, and a robber, and...".)